Error al abrir un formulario
Estoy intentando ingresar a un formulario de un sistema creado con visual basic .net que se encuentra en un servidor pero al querer entrar  me muestra este tipo de error, Cabe mencionar que en ese formulario trato de cargar un documento excel en un GridView y mandar sus datos a la BDD en Sql espero puedan ayudarme Saludos.


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Espera... que??? estas tratando de abrir que cosa donde?

Asi esta mejor.?
@gbianchi

Usas una clase que no está registrada en el servidor. Ya que mencionas que trabajas con Excel, suena a que el servidor no tiene instalado Office y tú estás usando las clases de automatización de Excel. También puede ser que si lo tenga instalado, pero en un bitness incompatible con el del servidor web. Es decir, si el sistema operativo es de 64 bits, el IIS será de 64 bits, el Office debiera ser también de 64 bits para poder interoperar con el IIS.

Está haciendo conexión por parte de un proxy, si es una página antigua que tenías en el server, verifica el proxy que está buscando, la ruta antigua debería de ser c:/programfile(86)/COMPlus Application/CodigoCLSID del error en pantalla.
La misma pantalla de error te dice que el proxy no está registrado.

Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Me temo que probablemente has leído mal la pregunta, ¿Dónde dice la pantalla de error que el proxy no está registrado?. Te invito a leer [answer].

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
